# How to open Openshift route on macOS?

Tags: openshift

I have installed Openshift CRC on my M1 Macbook using this instruction https://crc.dev/crc/getting_started/getting_started/installing/.
Version is `OpenShift 4.13.6`

I was able to create a simple deployment config for Java Spring Application by using `Import from Git` option and `Builder Image` import strategy (openjdk-8-ubi8). After that application was successfully deployed and I've got a route for it.
[image]

App repository is https://github.com/pratik037/spring-trial.

Unfortunately, I am unable to open this route on my Macbook - `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` .

Is there a way to edit my deployment config or route so that I can open my application by this URL or by some another?